# Pushing more assets to Heroku (after precompile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've got a new rails 3.1 site on Heroku and followed the instructions at this link http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting about precompiling assets for a 3.1 application. It basically tells you to do this

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and it worked for me. Yeah. However, I've decided to change a few images on the local site, and then pushed to Git and Heroku, but the images didn't appear on the Heroku site. I then tried to run this precompile command again but it didn't do anything on the site and I got this in the terminal...  Any ideas?

```
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby 
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby 
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@devise311/bin/rake assets:precompile:nondigest RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
```

Comment: This new 'labs' plugin http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile from heroku means you don't me to precompile assets as it makes config variables available at slug compile time now.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason it's working now if I just do a regular git push.

Answer (score 0):

I always run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` right before I push to my heroku remote. Is that what you did?